# Socket support using wamp in windows 7

Tags: php, mysql, windows-7, wamp

I'm running windows 7 and using WAMP for my local development. Now I Installed Cultbooking (sourceforge.net/projects/cultbooking/) in my wamp and can't finish my installation because it says sock "Socket support - Socket not supported". I don't know how I can enable my socket. I'm new to web development.

This is what I did, I download the Cultbooking from the (sourceforge.net/projects/cultbooking/) and drag the files to my 'www' directory of my wamp. Now when i pointed my browser to my localhost it say

---

PHP version >= 5.0       Yes

- zlib compression support    Available
- XML support     Available
- MySQL support   Available
- Socket support  Unavailable

configuration.php   Writeable

---

Now my only problem is my Socket support. How do I enable it? if you're in my shoes, Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that MySQL runs on TCP/IP by default on Windows and sockets on UNIX.

So you should try to change the Wampserver MySQL or PHP settings to use socket.

Look into you MySQL settings on Wampserver by click on the wampserver icon in the taskbar > MySQL > my.ini.

Look at here for more details.
http://www.devside.net/guides/windows/mysql

Hope that help.